# find- replace string function in C

Tags: c, string

There are a lot of find/replace functions available on the internet, but i can't find why this is not working...( my own solution )
Here is what i tried

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* strrpl(char *str, char* find, char *replace)
{
    int i;
    char *pt = strstr(str, find), *firstStr;

    firstStr = (char* )malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    // copy just until i find what i need to replace
    // i tried to specify the length of firstStr just with pt - str
    strncpy(firstStr, str, strlen(str) - strlen(pt));  

    strcat(firstStr, replace);
    strcat(firstStr, pt + strlen(find));

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(firstStr); i++)
        str[i] = firstStr[i];
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    char *s, *s1, *s2;
    s = (char* )malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    s1 = (char* )malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    s2 = (char* )malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", s1);
    scanf("%s", s2);
    scanf("%s", s);

    printf("%s", strrpl(s, s1, s2));
    return 0;
}
```

The compilation gives me the error "segmentation fault" but i can't figure what memmory is he trying to alloc and he can't. I overrided a memory block or something? Please help :)

Thanks

Comment: Segmentation fault doesn't mean it failed to allocate memory. That is reported by `malloc()` returning `NULL` (which you don't check for!). The fault means you overwrote valid memory, i.e. you have a bug. Run the program in a debugger, and/or Valgrind if available.

Comment: that is not a compilation error, if it is your compiler is having the problem, not your program. Another thing you should not call `strlen` in a `for` loop like that, it is expensive. You should instead store the value in a variable and use that.

Comment: You shouldn't use a `for`-loop at all for such a simple task, `memcpy` is there for you. And this is also where you have at least one bug, you don't terminate `str` with a `0` byte.

Comment: Memory allocated with malloc is never freed, so you got a memory leak with each strrpl function call.

Comment: thank you very much to all, i rechecked my code, and with scanf it only reads until `' '`(space character), and if the `find` string is in the middle, it will always return `NULL`, so i used `gets()` to read my strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the immediate problem: when `strstr` returns `NULL`, your code does not pay attention. Add this line:

```
char *pt = strstr(str, find), *firstStr;
if (!pt) return str;
```

Another problem is that the call of `strncpy` is incorrect:

```
strncpy(firstStr, str, strlen(str) - strlen(pt));
```

it will leave `firstStr` unterminated, because `str` is longer than the substring being copied. The subsequent call

```
strcat(firstStr, replace);
```

will operate on a string that is not null-terminated, causing undefined behavior.

"Shotgun" approach to fixing it would be to use `calloc` instead of `malloc` to put zeros into `firstStr`. A more precise approach would be placing `'\0'` at the end of the copied substring.

With these fixes in place, your code runs OK ([demo](http://ideone.com/BT3sa2)). However, there are several issues that need to be addressed:

- **You do not free any of the resources that you allocate dynamically** - this results in memory leaks.
- **You do not compute how much memory to allocate** - If a 5-character string is replaced for a 100-character string in a 100-character string, you overrun the temporary buffer.
- **You are using `strncpy` incorrectly** - the function is intended for fixed-length strings. Use `memcpy` instead.
- **You are using `strcat` instead of `memcpy` or `strcpy`** - this is inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

> I overrided a memory block or something?

You have:

1. A potential buffer overflow when you allocate `firstStr`. Who says the result will be less than 100 characters?
2. Another potential buffer overflow when you copy the answer back to the input string. Who says it will fit?
3. A potential buffer overflow each time you use `scanf`.
4. A memory leak each time you call `malloc`.
5. An inefficient implementation of `strcpy` just before `return str;`.
6. A crash (formally, undefined behaviour) when the input string does not contain the replacement string. `strstr` returns `NULL` when there is no match and you never check for it.
7. A potential issue with `strncpy` which leaves your string not `NUL`-terminated if there's not enough space for `NUL`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not checked for the return value of strstr.
Try the below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* strrpl(char *str, char* find, char *replace)
{
    int i;
    char *pt = strstr(str, find);
    char *firstStr;
    if(pt == NULL){
        printf("cannot find string \n");
        return NULL;
    }

    firstStr = (char* )malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

    // copy just until i find what i need to replace
    // i tried to specify the length of firstStr just with pt - str

    strncpy(firstStr, str, strlen(str) - strlen(pt)); 
    strcat(firstStr, replace);
    strcat(firstStr, pt + strlen(find));

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(firstStr); i++)
        str[i] = firstStr[i];
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    char *s, *s1, *s2, *s3;
    s = (char* )malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    s1 = (char* )malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    s2 = (char* )malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    s3 = (char* )malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

    scanf("%s", s);//input string
    scanf("%s", s1);//string to find
    scanf("%s", s2);//string to replace

    s3 = strrpl(s, s1, s2);
    if(s3 != NULL)
        printf("%s \n",s3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All the allocated memory should be freed after the usage.

Comment: thank you very much, i rechecked my code, and with scanf it only reads until ' '(space character), and if the 'find' string is in the middle, it will always return 'NULL'

Answer (score 0):

What about memmove ?

Assuming that src is long enough when shifting to the right :

```c
char *str_rpl(char *src, char *pattern, char *rpl) {
  char *dest, *origin;
  char *found = strstr(src, pattern);
  
  if(!found) {
    return NULL;
  }

  /* Shifting right or left to fit new size */
  dest = found;
  origin = found + strlen(pattern);

  if(strlen(rpl) > strlen(pattern)) {
    dest += strlen(rpl);
  }   
  else {
    origin -= strlen(rpl);
  }   
  memmove(dest, origin, strlen(origin) + 1);

  /* Replacement */
  memcpy(found, rpl, strlen(rpl));

  return found;
}
```